# Solve for $(2t-1)^{-1}$ in binomial and hypergeometric form

Tags: binomial-coefficients, hypergeometric-function

Solve for $(2t-1)^{-1}$ in binomial and hypergeometric form. We have from the binomial theorem
$$(a+x)^k=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{k}{n}a^{k-n}x^n$$
For this instance, $a=2t, x=-1, k=-1$
$$(2t-1)^{-1}=\lim_{m \to \infty}\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{(-1)!}{n!}(2t)^{-1-n}(-1)^n$$
I have that $(-1)!=(-1)^n(1)_n$,
$$(2t-1)^{-1}=\lim_{m \to \infty}\frac{1}{2t}\sum_{n=0}^m\frac{(1)_n}{n!}\left(\frac{1}{2t}\right)^n=\frac{\left(\sqrt{e}\right)^{t^{-1}}}{2t}$$

Which produces the following hypergeometric function $_2F_1(1;-;-;\frac{1}{2t})$

The equality above does not work for $t=1$ and so I question whether this approach is correct?

Comment: Actually i only realised that $(1)_n$ cancels out with $n!$ so it becomes a geometric series when $|t| < 1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We expand the rational function $\frac{1}{2t-1}$ at $t=0$.

> The binomial expansion at $t=0$ gives
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2t-1}}&=-(1-2t)^{-1}
> =-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-1}{n}(-2t)^n\tag{1}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2t)^n}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> which corresponds with the expansion as *geometric series*.

In (1) we use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ so that
$
\binom{-1}{n}=\binom{n}{n}(-1)^n=(-1)^n
$.

> From (2) we derive a representation as hypergeometric series:
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{1}{2t-1}}&
> =-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2t)^n
> =-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n!\frac{(2t)^n}{n!}\\
> &=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1)_n\frac{(2t)^n}{n!}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=-{}_1F_0(1;0;2t)}
> \end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, very helpful! I was not sure whether I factor out the minus sign, so when you say "expansion at $t=0$", does the approach I suggested not work then with the binomial expansion set-up? I notice we produce exactly two different results, all because of the binomial series composition

Comment: @joe_bill.dollar: You're welcome. Your expansion is not the intended one, as in your expansion $t$ has negative powers, which is a *Laurent expansion*. Here we want a *power series expansion*, so that $t$ has non-negative powers only. You just need to factor out $a$ and not $x$.