# Solve for $\int_0^1 t^{s+a-1}(1-t)^{a-1}(2t-1)^{-1}dt$

Tags: definite-integrals, hypergeometric-function, beta-function

Solve for $$\int_0^1 t^{s+a-1}(1-t)^{a-1}(2t-1)^{-1}dt$$
I first convert $(2t-1)^{-1}$ to its binomial and then geometric form following [solve for (2t-1)^-1 in binomial and hypergeometric form](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4759012/solve-for-2t-1-1-in-binomial-and-hypergeometric-form)

$$-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1)_n2^n}{n!}\int_0^1t^{s+a+n-1}(1-t)^{a-1}dt$$

Notice the integral is a beta function $B(s+a+n,a)$, so the integral then becomes

$$\frac{\Gamma(s+2a)}{\Gamma(s+a)\Gamma(a)}\int_0^1 t^{s+a-1}(1-t)^{a-1}(2t-1)^{-1}dt$$

We know the hypergeometric integral is
$$_2F_1(a;b;c;x)=\frac{\Gamma(c)}{\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(a)}\int_0^1t^{a-1}(1-t)^{c-a-1}(1-xt)^{-b}dt$$

So I then have
$$-_2F_1(s+a;1;2a+s;2)=\frac{\Gamma(s+2a)}{\Gamma(s+a)\Gamma(a)}\int_0^1 t^{s+a-1}(1-t)^{a-1}(2t-1)^{-1}dt$$

Comment: See e.g. theorem 1.1 in https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2009.02.035  or theorem 1.1 in https://etna.math.kent.edu/vol.25.2006/pp115-120.dir/pp115-120.html .